# Retrieve events number from SharePoint calendar using JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-jsom

I have a SharePoint calendar list, and I'm looking for a script to retrieve the number of events on a day. For example, for today, 10 August, I want to just retrieve the number of events stored in my calendar.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem with Querying Calendars in JavaScript: Recurrence

Ordinarily retrieving data from SharePoint with JavaScript is really straightforward (at least for versions beyond SharePoint 2007) using either REST or the JavaScript Object Model. However, calendars have functionality for creating recurring events which can complicate things.

For example, a recurring event may have a start date of two years ago and an end date many years in the future, but maybe the event itself only actually occurs on the third Tuesday of every month. If you just query the list and try to compare today's date against the start date and end date to see if they overlap, that recurring event will show up in your results (even though today is not the third Tuesday of the month).

In server-side code you can get around this by setting the **[ExpandRecurrence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.expandrecurrence.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)** property to true on the **SPQuery** object used to query the list. However, as of SP2010 and SP2013, that property is **not** exposed on the equivalent JavaScript Object Model.

---

### Workaround: Using the Lists.GetListItems web service**

An alternative is to use one of the old web services that are still floating around... specifically the **Lists** web service accessible at `/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`. This web service has a `GetListItems` method that accepts a SOAP message in which you can specify a query option to expand recurrence as you would on the server side.

Here's an example demonstrating how you can query the **Lists** web service using plain JavaScript:

```
// Set webUrl and listGuid to values specific to your site and list
var webUrl = "http://server/sitewhereyourlistexists";
var listGuid = "{000000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"

// An XMLHttpRequest object is used to access the web service
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = webUrl + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");

// The message body consists of an XML document 
// with SOAP elements corresponding to the GetListItems method parameters
// i.e. listName, query, and queryOptions
var data = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" + 
        "<soap:Body>" +
        "<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">" + 
                "<listName>"+listGuid+"</listName>" + 
                "<query>" + 
                    "<Query><Where>" +
                        "<DateRangesOverlap>" + 
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\"/>"+
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"/>"+
                            "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>"+
                            "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today/></Value>"+
                        "</DateRangesOverlap>"+
                    "</Where></Query>"+
                "</query>" +
                "<queryOptions>"+
                    "<QueryOptions>"+
                        "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>"+
                    "</QueryOptions>"+
                "</queryOptions>" +
        "</GetListItems>" +
        "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>";

// Here we define what code we want to run upon successfully getting the results
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var doc = xhr.responseXML;
            // grab all the "row" elements from the XML results
            var rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
            var results = "Today's Schedule ("+rows.length+"):\n\n";
            var events = {};
            for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++){
                var id = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_FSObjType"); // prevent duplicates from appearing in results
                    if(!events[id]){ 
                        events[id] = true;
                        var allDay = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_fAllDayEvent"),
                            title = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_Title"),
                            start = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_EventDate"); 
                        var index = start.indexOf(" "); 
                        var date = start.substring(5,index)+"-"+start.substring(2,4); // get the date in MM-dd-yyyy format
                        start = start.substring(index, index+6); // get the start time in hh:mm format
                        var end = rows[i].getAttribute("ows_EndDate"); 
                        index = end.indexOf(" "); end = end.substring(index,index+6); // get the end time in hh:mm format
                        results += date + " " + (allDay == "1" ? "All Day\t" : start + " to " + end ) + " \t " + title + "\n";
                    }
                }
                alert(results);
            }else{
                alert("Error "+xhr.status);
            }   
    }
};

// Finally, we actually kick off the query
xhr.send(data);
```

---

### Checking ranges other than today's date

In the `<Value>` child node of the `<DateRangesOverlap>` node, you can specify `<Now />`, `<Today />`, `<Week />`, `<Month />`, or `<Year />`.

Week, Month, and Year will check for events within the same week, month, or year of the current date.

To check a date range relative to some date other than today's, you can add a `<CalendarDate>` node to the `<QueryOptions>` node of the CAML query, as seen below.

```
"<query>" + 
    "<Query><Where>" + 
        "<DateRangesOverlap>" + 
            "<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\"/>"+ 
            "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\"/>"+ 
            "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>"+ 
                "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Week /></Value>"+ 
        "</DateRangesOverlap>"+ 
    "</Where></Query>"+ 
"</query>" + 
"<queryOptions>"+ 
    "<QueryOptions>"+ 
        "<ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>"+ 
        "<CalendarDate>2017-03-10</CalendarDate>" +
    "</QueryOptions>"+ 
"</queryOptions>" +
```

Note that values of `<Now />` and `<Year />` do not seem to respect the `CalendarDate` value.

Comment: thanks for the answer , in my case i have a calendar with events categories ("holidays", meetings , ....) . user can add events by category to the calendar.
i wanna retrieve number of specific event in the current day.
example : for today 16 August i wanna check how many meetings are in my calendar , and retrieve only the number of meetings in a html div . <div id="events"></div>.
my code should retrieve number of current day and day+1.
thanks for the help

Comment: @Thriggle: Thanks for your solution. The issue I am facing is responseXML is  null while responseText has the result. Tried converting string to XML and reading the rows. But it always shows rows as 0. Any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: @Thriggle: Figured out the issue. Instead of using `doc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")` I changed `doc.getElementsByTagName("row")` and that worked!

Comment: Is there a way to expand for more than just Today? We want to expand all dates greater than or equal to today.

Comment: @Rothrock, I've updated the answer to show how you can expand recurrence for date ranges other than today. You're limited to increments of weeks and months, unfortunately.